# 1000 users a day for 10 minutes equal what concurrent load?

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, load

Is there a formula that will tell me the max/average # of concurrent users I would expect to have with a population of 1000 users a day using an app for 10 minutes?

Comment: Not enough information.  Are all 1000 users in the same location/time zone?  Do they all work the same shift?  Concurrent use will depend on all these and more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1000 users X 10 minutes = 10,000 user minutes

10,000 user minutes / 1440 minutes in a day = 6.944 average # of concurrent users

If you are looking for better estimates of concurrent users, I would suggest putting [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) on your site. It would give you an accurate reading of highs, lows, and averages for your site.

Comment: That assumes linear access by users over a 24 hour period... which is a very large assumption.

Comment: agreed, but with the information given there is not a whole lot more to go on.

Comment: It's a self serve reference app, similar in usage pattern to say Wikipedia.org.

Comment: So it's usage is worldwide, 24/7 ? If so, then I think you would have *less* highs and lows and as such the number would be closer to 7 as the math dictates. However, I would still suggest using google analytics to get some better more concrete numbers. Also, if the user group is only in one area of the world then you would have say, 16 hour day X 60 min = 960 min/day

then 10,000 / 960 = 10.41 concurrent users

Answer (score 7):

In the worst case scenario, all 1000 users use the app at the same time, so max # oc concurrent users is 1000.

1000 users * 10 minutes = 10000 total minutes

One day has 24 hours * 60 minutes = 1440 minutes.

Assume normal distribution, you would expect 10000 / 1440 = 6.9 users on average using your app concurrently. However, normal distribution is not a valid assumption since you probably won't expect a lot of users in the middle of a night.

Comment: It is not called normal distribution, it is called rectangular distribution. Normal distribution is something other.

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming there was a steady arrival pattern, people visited the site with an equal distribution, you would have:

( Users * Visit Length in Minutes) / (Minutes in a Day)
  or
(1000 * 10 ) / 1440

Which would be about 7 concurrent users

Of course, you would never have an equal distribution like that.  You can take a stab at the anticipated pattern, and distribute the load based on that pattern.  Best bet would be to monitor the traffic for a bit, with a decent sampling of user traffic.

Answer (score 2):

That depends quite a bit on their usage pattern and no generic formula can cover it.

As an extreme example, if this is a timecard application, you would have a large peak at the start and stop of each work day, with scattered access between start and stop as people work on different projects, and almost no access outside of working hours.

Can you describe the usage pattern you expect?

Comment: Wow we both used a timecard application in our answers. I saw the "2 answers posted" while I was writing, but didn't see your answer until after mine was posted. Guess that makes it a good example, no?

Comment: It's a self serve reference app, similar in usage pattern to say Wikipedia.

Comment: Yeah the timecard app is a classic case when discussing load distributions.  I'm sure I picked it up from an book/article somewhere in the distant past but not sure where/when.

Answer (score 1):

Not accurately.

Will the usage be spread evenly over the day or are there events that will cause everyone to use their 10 mintes at the same time?

For example lets compare a general purpose web site with a time card entry system.

General purpose web site will have ebbs and flows throughout the day with clusters of time when you have lots of users (during work hours...).

The time card entry system might have all 1000 people hitting the system within a 15 minute span of time twice a day.

Simple math can show you an average, but people don't generally behave "on average"...

Answer (score 1):

As is universally said, the answer is dependent upon the distribution of when people "arrive." If it's equally likely for someone to arrive at 3:23 AM as at 9:01 AM, max_concurrent is low; if everyone checks in between 8:55 AM and 9:30 AM, max_concurrent is high (and if response time slows depending on current load, so that the 'average' time on the site goes up significantly when there are lots of people on the site...).

A model is only as good as its inputs, but having said that, if you have a good sense of usage patterns, a Monte Carlo model might be a good idea. (If you have access to a person with a background in statistics or probability, they can do the math just based on the distribution parameters, but a Monte Carlo model is easier for most people to create and manipulate.)

In comments, you say that it's a "self-serve reference app similar to Wikipedia," but your relatively low usage means that you cannot *rely* on the power of large numbers to "dampen out" your arrival curves over 24-hours.